Are there efficient sampling techniques to leverage if my function has a seperable structure of functions?
I'm considering the posterior of a parametric model via the Bayesian approach. More specificity, I have a parametric model $u(p_1,p_2, p_3) = u_1(p_1) \times u_2(p_2) \times u_3(p_3)$ and I want to study the posterior distributions of $\mathbf{p}= \{p_1, p_2, p_3\}$ given some data $\mathcal {D}$. Hence Bayes' formula returns:
$$p(\mathbf{p}|D) = \frac{p(D|\mathbf{p})\times p(\mathbf{p})}{\text{evidence}}.$$
Suppose my prior $p(\mathbf{p})$ can be written as $p(p_1) \times p(p_2) \times p(p_3)$, my likelihood function is a Gaussian centered at the output of the model:$$p(D|\mathbf{p}) = \mathcal{N}(u(\mathbf{p}),\sigma^2)$$
Are there efficient sampling techniques to leverage the seperable structure of
$$u(p_1,p_2, p_3) = u_1(p_1) \times u_2(p_2) \times u_3(p_3)$$
Here is an example. Suppose we have 5 sampling points along each dimension, in total we have 125 points.
If $u(p_1,p_2, p_3)$
is not seperable, we may have to go through each data point in the 3 dimensional space. This can be challenging for high dimensional cases. However, if $u(p_1,p_2, p_3)$ seperable, we can just go through each 1D domain and then use tensor product to compute ue to the seperation of varible, we can use tensor product to compute u(p1,p2,p3)

Please don't just re-post questions that have already been closed for one reason or another... better to try to address the issue(s) leading to the closure.
